Why do I get missing value error in XGBoost when it is supposed to be supported?
I read that in the latest versions of XGBoost, the model can handle missing values. I am using the model on some data that contains for example, the BMI, bloodpressure, age, binary data (yes/no) and some categorical data, with the target as the number of days. I removed missing values from the target, but kept the rest of the data whether it has missing values or not, as it is necessary(not all people had their blood pressure or BMI measured, but their data is still relevant). When I run the model, I keep getting the error :
Error in na.fail.default(list(Days = c(5.73055, 15.29236 , : missing values in object.
But shouldn't this be no problem as it should be able to handle missing values?
This is some of my code:
library(caret)
library(xgboost)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

model <- model[!is.na(model$days), ]

model <- model[!is.na(model$days), ]
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(model[["days"]], p = 0.7, list = FALSE, times = 1)
train_data <- main_attempt[trainIndex, ]
test_data <- main_attempt[-trainIndex, ]

Define the control method for training
train_control <- trainControl(
method = "cv", # k-fold cross-validation
number = 10, # number of folds
verboseIter = TRUE # display training progress
)

Define the hyperparameter grid
tune_grid <- expand.grid(
nrounds = c(50, 100, 150), # number of boosting rounds
eta = c(0.01, 0.1, 0.3), # learning rate
max_depth = c(3, 6, 9), # maximum depth of a tree
gamma = c(0, 0.1, 0.5), # minimum loss reduction required to make a further partition
colsample_bytree = c(0.6, 0.8, 1), # subsample ratio of columns when constructing each tree
min_child_weight = c(1, 5, 10), # minimum sum of instance weight (hessian) needed in a child
subsample = c(0.6, 0.8, 1) # subsample ratio of the training instances
)

Train the model using caret's train function
set.seed(123)
xgb_model <- train(
Stay_days ~ ., # formula for the model
data = train_data, # dataset
method = "xgbTree", # xgboost algorithm
trControl = train_control, # control parameters
tuneGrid = tune_grid, # hyperparameter grid
metric = "MAE" # evaluation metric (Mean Absolute Error)
)
#I get the error here

